# Python code to capture present frame and kill past frames.

Tags: python, opencv

I am writing code to extract text from live video. I write the code and it,s executing well. But the problem is that it is taking all the frames and running slowly. Means giving delay of 10 seconds. Is there any command to kill past frames and take present frame for processing.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import time
import math
from PIL import Image
from pytesseract import image_to_string

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while(True):
    cap.open
    ret, img = cap.read()

    img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2BGRA)
    kernel = np.ones((1, 1), np.uint8)
    img = cv2.dilate(img, kernel, iterations=1)
    img = cv2.erode(img, kernel, iterations=1)
    img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(img,(5,5),0)
    ret3,th3 = cv2.threshold(blur,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

    cv2.imshow('frame', th3)
    text = image_to_string(th3)
    print text
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        out = cv2.imwrite('capture.jpg', frame)
        break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly.
VideoCapture works by giving you the next frame to process in order.  If it is slow, it is up to you to process it or not.

One common solution is just process every i frames.

But you can also change the Frame Per Seconds rate with:
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS, 10)